# React Native: Touch/Press not working after navigating to one screen

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to React Native and I have been building an app. After navigating to one screen in the app, I am unable to zoom in on an image as well as press any button, however I am still able to drag drawer navigation and interact with it.

I have tried to go back and see if the code that has been added has anything to do with it but the problem persisted even after I went to my previous version.

Code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, PixelRatio, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import Header from './Header.js';
import Svg, {Path} from 'react-native-svg';

enableScreens();
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height: 1000 / PixelRatio.get(),
    width: 1100 / PixelRatio.get(),
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  radioOne: {
    flex: 1,
    right: 75,
    marginBottom: 75,
  },
  container: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  scrollView: {
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  button: {
    top: 1000,
  }
});

const fun = () => {
  alert("Hello");
};
//x1 = start of the Line
//x2 = end of the Line
//y1 = start of the line on y axis
//y2 = end of the line on y axis

export default function Barrow({ navigation }) {
  //const array = ["./barrows.jpg"];
  //const building = array.map(building);
  const map_change = "./barrow2.jpg";
  // Barrow 1st floor paths
  let studentService_Medical = "M300 260 L65 260 L65 245";
  let studentService_union = "M300 260 L185 260 L185 270";
  let studentService_sportsHall = "M300 260 L155 260 L155 250 M155 260 L205 260 L205 250";
  let studentService_careers = "M300 260 L270 260 L270 270";
  let studentService_stairs = "M300 260 L265 260 L265 255 L235 255 M300 260 L150 260 L150 255 H150 130 ";
  let studentService_sportsOffice = "M300 260 L270 260 L270 215 H270 280";

  // Barrow 2nd Floor

    return (
        <><Header title='Barrow' navigation={navigation} />
          <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: '15%', position: 'absolute'}}>
              <Image source={require(map_change)} style={styles.image}/>
              <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
              </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Svg>
              <Path d={studentService_sportsOffice} fill="none" stroke="red" width="10" />
            </Svg>
          </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

Is there something that I am missing so it behaves like it should or is the problem somewhere else in the app?

**EDIT:** zoom and button presses do not work in the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

The Image component from react-native doesn't support zooming, you can use this package instead https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-zoom#readme

Comment: Zoom is not a problem on this screen but rather a different one, however after getting into the screen which code is above I am unable to use zoom or any buttons in the entire app. Apologies for not being more clear in the question.